# Insert with relationships in AdonisJS with transaction

Tags: postgresql, async-await, transactions, adonis.js

I'm new to this JS Word, I read the Adonis and Knex doc, but I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Adonis: https://preview.adonisjs.com/guides/database/transactions and https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_transactions

knex: http://knexjs.org/#Transactions

In the case when nothing goes wrong all the data are stored with no problem, but when I do a error on propose just to test the transaction I can notice that the "empresas" table had a record and the other tables are empty, I supose that when occurs an error all the tables need to be empty, by the transaction's rollback() function. Can someone enlighten me here?
Using: Adonis with postgres

this are my migrations:

table empresas:

```
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')

class EmpresaSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('empresas', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.text('codigo').notNullable()
      table.text('tipo').notNullable()
      table.text('origem').notNullable()
      table.bigInteger('grupo_id').notNullable()
      table.text('nome_fantasia')
      table.text('razao_social')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('empresas')
  }
}

module.exports = EmpresaSchema
```

table contatos:

```
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')

class ContatosSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('contatos', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table
        .integer('tipo_id')
        .unsigned()
        .notNullable()
        .references('id')
        .inTable('contato_tipos')
      table.text('nome').notNullable()
      table.text('dado').notNullable()
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('contatos')
  }
}

module.exports = ContatosSchema
```

table empresa_contatos:

```
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')

class EmpresaContatosSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('empresa_contatos', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table
        .integer('empresa_id')
        .unsigned()
        .references('id')
        .inTable('empresas')
        .onUpdate('CASCADE')
        .onDelete('CASCADE')
        .index()

      table
        .integer('contato_id')
        .unsigned()
        .references('id')
        .inTable('contatos')
        .onUpdate('CASCADE')
        .onDelete('CASCADE')
        .index()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('empresa_contatos')
  }
}

module.exports = EmpresaContatosSchema
```

My models:

Empresa model:

```
'use strict'

/** @type {typeof import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Lucid/Model')} */
const Model = use('Model')

class Empresa extends Model {
  contatos () {
    return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Contato').pivotTable('empresa_contatos')
  }
}

module.exports = Empresa
```

Contato model:

```
'use strict'

/** @type {typeof import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Lucid/Model')} */
const Model = use('Model')

class Contato extends Model {
  static get table () {
    return 'contatos'
  }

  empresa () {
    return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Empresa').pivotTable('empresa_contatos')
  }
}

module.exports = Contato
```

And this is a part of my EmpresaController:

```
'use strict'

const Database = use('Database')
const Empresa = use('App/Models/Empresa')
const Contato = use('App/Models/Contato')
const Sequence = use('App/Controllers/Http/SequenceController')


class EmpresaController {
  async customCreate ({ request, response, auth }) {
    const trx = await Database.beginTransaction()
    try {
      const { enderecos, contatos, ...data } = request.all()
      if (data.endereco.logradouro !== '') {
        enderecos.push(data.endereco)
      }

      if (data.contato.nome !== '') {
        contatos.push(data.contato)
      }

      const codigo = await Sequence.gerarNovoCodigoCliente(auth.user.grupo_id, trx)

      let empresa = null
      await Empresa.create({
        codigo: codigo,
        grupo_id: 1,
        tipo: data.tipo,
        origem: data.origem,
        nome_fantasia: data.nome_fantasia,
        razao_social: data.razao_social
      }, trx)
        .then(response => {
          empresa = response
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('error empresa:')
          console.log(error)
        })

      contatos.forEach(async contato => {
        let novosContato = null

        await Contato.create({
          nome: contato.nome,
          dado: contato.dado,
          tipo_id: contato.tipo_contato.id
        }, trx)
          .then(response => {
            novosContato = response
            console.log('contato ok')
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('error contato:')
            console.log(error)
          })

        await empresa.contatos().attach(novosContato.id, null, trx)
          .then(response => {
            console.log('attach ok')
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('error attach:')
            console.log(error)
          })
      })

      await trx.commit()
      return response.ok(empresa)
    } catch (error) {
      await trx.rollback()
      return response.badRequest(error.message)
    }
  }
}

module.exports = EmpresaController
```

I already tried put each async function on a const and resolve all with promise.all approach, and get the same problem, I really don't know but I guess that "const empresa = await Empresa.create(.......)" is commiting the transaction and running the everything else after it.

(edit)log:

```
error contato:
Error: Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info
    at completedError (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:261:9)
    at /app/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:231:22
From previous event:
    at Client_PG.trxClient.query (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/transaction.js:229:33)
    at Runner.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:138:36)
From previous event:
    at /app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:47:21
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
From previous event:
    at Runner.run (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:33:30)
    at Builder.Target.then (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:23:43)
warning: 
  WARNING: Adonis has detected an unhandled promise rejection, which may
  cause undesired behavior in production.
  To stop this warning, use catch() on promises or wrap await
  calls inside try/catch.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
    at /app/app/Controllers/Http/EmpresaController.js:165:54
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass transaction reference to create also...

Just add trx here:

```
  const empresa = await Empresa.create({
    codigo: codigo,
    grupo_id: 1,
    tipo: data.tipo,
    origem: data.origem,
    nome_fantasia: data.nome_fantasia,
    razao_social: data.razao_social
  }, trx)   <-- adding trx to create!
```

More info here: https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_transactions

Comment: Yeah, I forget it, I have changed a little the original code (updated on post) cause I can't get the value with const empresa = await... need to put it on response to get the value, and now i get a new error (with the trx on the create put it on log in the original post)

Comment: You are probably running commit() on transaction multiple times... My best guess is inside gerarNovoCodigoCliente method... Offtopic, learn about async/await and promises, you are doing strange stuff